# Не получается изменить файл default.json Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, консоль, windows-10

Кто знает, есть 2 файла настроек - settings.json(click) и defaults.json(alt+click). settings.json нормально изменяется и никаких проблем нету, а вот с defaults выскакивает это:

[image: скрин шибка]

**Вот данные со свойств безопасности файлов:**

[image: Свойства безопасности settings.json]

[image: Свойство безопасности defaukts.json]

Что странно, когда заходишь в свойства settings.json -> безопасность, то под "Группами и пользователями" есть кнопка "изменить", а в свойствах файла defaults.json нету. И доступ к неизвестной учетной записи у settings полный, а у defaults частичный, но изменить его я никак не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Доброй ночи.
Я пытался изменить этот файл, для добавления вкладки "Ubuntu".
Сохранить файл после внесения изменений у меня не получилось...
Мне удалось переместить этот элемент в другую директорию (перенес тупо на рабочий стол). Там я его изменил, но вернуть обратно не хватило прав. Поменял разрешения на папку, с кучей "отказано в доступе" и странной ошибкой разрешений, ниже добавлю скрин. После смены разрешений файл всё равно не удалось переместить в нужную папку, !но долгожданная вкладка "Ubuntu" появилась в терминале...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Извините, это ответ или новый вопрос?